# How can I use a random user agent whenever I send a request?

Tags: scrapy

i know how to use random (fake) user agent in scrapy. but after i run scrapy. i could see only one random user agent on terminal. so i guessed maybe 'settings.py' run only one time when i run scrapy. if scrapy work really like this and send 1000 request to some web page to collect 1000 data, scrapy will just send same user agent. Surely it can be easy to get ban i think.

can you tell me how can i send random user agent when scrapy send request to some website?

i used this lib(?) in my scrapy project.
after i set `faker` in `user-agent` in `settings.py`

```
https://pypi.org/project/Faker/
```

```
from faker import Faker 

fake = Faker() 
Faker.seed(fake.random_number()) 
fake_user_agent = fake.chrome() 

USER_AGENT = fake_user_agent
```

in settings.py i wrote like this. can it work well ??

Comment: Are you using `scrapy-fake-useragent`? It will change the user-agent on every request

Comment: @tomjn thank you ! i used ```scrapy-fake-useragent``` before, but it doesn't have enough random user-agent data. so i use ```faker````'s random user agent. um i didn't know ```scrapy-fake-useragent``` change user-agent on every requets. um thx !

Comment: You can also use `faker` with `scrapy-fake-useragent` How are you using `faker`? It sounds like you just set the user-agent once in the settings?

Comment: @tomjn i added that code on the QUESTION ! check it please!

Comment: You are right that your code will just set the user agent once (when `settings.py` is loaded), and not per request. If you want an answer describing how to use `scrapy-fake-useragent`with `faker` properly I can tell you, but you said you know how to use it?

Comment: @tomjn of course i know how to use it lol. i didn't know it make different user-agent in every request. i thought user-agent is setted only one time when i run spider(```scrapy crawl blahblah```). and when i run spider again it change other user-agent. lol. thx!

Answer (score 2):

If you are setting `USER_AGENT` in your `settings.py` like in your question then you will just get a single (random) user agent for your entire crawl.

You have a few options if you want to set a fake user agent for each request.

#### Option 1: Explicitly set User-Agent per request

This approach involves setting the `user-agent` in the headers of your [`Request`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects) directly. In your spider code you can import `Faker` like you do above but then call e.g. `fake.chrome()` on every `Request`. For example

```py
# At the top of your file
from faker import Faker 

# This can be a global or class variable
fake = Faker() 

...

# When you make a Request 
yield Request(url, headers={"User-Agent": fake.chrome()})
```

#### Option 2: Write a middleware to do this automatically

I won't go into this because you might as well use one that already exists

#### Option 3: Use an existing middleware to do this automatically (such as [`scrapy-fake-useragent`](https://pypi.org/project/scrapy-fake-useragent/))

If you have lots of requests in your code option 1 isn't so nice, so you can use a `Middleware` to do this for you. Once you've installed `scrapy-fake-useragent` you can set it up in your settings file as described on the webpage

```py
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
    'scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RetryUserAgentMiddleware': 401,
}

FAKEUSERAGENT_PROVIDERS = [
    'scrapy_fake_useragent.providers.FakeUserAgentProvider',
    'scrapy_fake_useragent.providers.FakerProvider',  
    'scrapy_fake_useragent.providers.FixedUserAgentProvider',
]
```

Using this you'll get a new `user-agent` per `Request` and if a `Request` fails you'll also get a new random `user-agent`. One of the key parts of setting this up is `FAKEUSERAGENT_PROVIDERS`. This tells us where to get the `User-Agent` from. They are tried in the order they are defined, so the second will be tried if the first one fails for some reason (if getting the user-agent fails, not if the `Request` fails). Note that if you want to use `Faker` as the primary provider, then you should put that one first in the list

```py
FAKEUSERAGENT_PROVIDERS = [
    'scrapy_fake_useragent.providers.FakerProvider',
    'scrapy_fake_useragent.providers.FakeUserAgentProvider',     
    'scrapy_fake_useragent.providers.FixedUserAgentProvider',
]
```

There are other configuration options (such as using a random chrome-like user-agent, listed in the `scrapy-fake-useragent` docs.

#### Example spider

Here is an example spider. For convenience I set the settings inside the spider, but you can put these into your `settings.py` file.

```py
# fake_user_agents.py
from scrapy import Spider


class FakesSpider(Spider):
    name = "fakes"
    start_urls = ["http://quotes.toscrape.com/"]
    custom_settings = dict(
        DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES={
            "scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware": None,
            "scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware": None,
            "scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RandomUserAgentMiddleware": 400,
            "scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RetryUserAgentMiddleware": 401,
        },
        FAKEUSERAGENT_PROVIDERS=[
            "scrapy_fake_useragent.providers.FakerProvider",
            "scrapy_fake_useragent.providers.FakeUserAgentProvider",
            "scrapy_fake_useragent.providers.FixedUserAgentProvider",
        ],
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        # Print out the user-agent of the request to check they are random
        print(response.request.headers.get("User-Agent"))

        next_page = response.css("li.next a::attr(href)").get()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)
```

Then if I run this with `scrapy runspider fake_user_agents.py --nolog` the output is

```py
b'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; PPC Mac OS X 10 11_0) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.811.0 Safari/533.1'
b'Opera/8.18.(Windows NT 6.2; tt-RU) Presto/2.9.169 Version/11.00'
b'Opera/8.40.(X11; Linux i686; ka-GE) Presto/2.9.176 Version/11.00'
b'Opera/9.42.(X11; Linux x86_64; sw-KE) Presto/2.9.180 Version/12.00'
b'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; PPC Mac OS X 10 5_1 rv:6.0; cy-GB) AppleWebKit/533.45.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.3 Safari/533.45.2'
b'Opera/8.17.(X11; Linux x86_64; crh-UA) Presto/2.9.161 Version/11.00'
b'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/3.1)'
b'Mozilla/5.0 (Android 3.1; Mobile; rv:55.0) Gecko/55.0 Firefox/55.0'
b'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows CE; Trident/5.0)'
b'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC Mac OS X 10 11_9; rv:1.9.4.20) Gecko/2019-07-26 10:00:35 Firefox/9.0'
```

Comment: thx !. i setted ```DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES{}``` and ```FAKEUSERAGENT_PROVIDERS{}``` on settings.py. but it work so late, when it get one date it spend more than 180sec, even it can go into mongodb...

Comment: I don’t understand your comment. This sounds like a different problem?

Comment: i edited my question, can you read and give me answer please ..?

Comment: @bayayaqd You shouldn't edit your question after your first one is answered, you should ask a new question. Please can you roll back your edits and ask a new question?

Comment: thx to comment! omg sorry ,,, i don't know how to do that... if i summary my first question is ```how can i use random useragent everytitme when i send resquest?```

Comment: @bayayaqd I've rolled it back for you. If you are making minor clarifications then it is fine to edit, but here you change the question to something about `mongodb`. If you are happy with this answer then please accept it. I'll try and look at your new question later on.

Comment: oh frankly it was becasue of this msg "You have reached your question limit"... sorry and thx

Comment: When I reproduce the exact spider code you provided in your answer, I get the same successful results, which is a different user agent each time. However, when I move the custom settings to the settings.py file, the spider keeps falling back to the FixedUserAgent attribute, meaning I get the same user agent every time. Any idea why that might be happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scrapy-user-agents`. This middleware has more than 2200 user agents.
For using of this install the library with:

```
pip install scrapy-user-agents
```

Then in your `settings.py` file add this lines:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy_user_agents.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 200,
}
```

Above
`scrapy_user_agents.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware`
is a number that you can set max to 2200!

By using above strategy, you can see used user agent at your log
such as below image.
Enjoy it!

[image]